# Should you convert exceptions to assertions to disable them at the customer?

Tags: java, exception, assert

A fried of my started to use exception in his Java project. Since an uncaught exceptions terminates the program he essentially converted all exceptions to assertions. He can therefore turn of all exceptions at the customers site. (In reality he does not need to disable them, rather he has to enables them with `-ea`/`-enableassertions` during development.)

```
class Logger {
    public static void logException(Throwable e) {
    assert false : e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to disable exceptions at the customers site? What alternatives are there and what are the important drawbacks of his approach?

Please note that he is very determined at disabling exceptions at the customer. (Therefore answers of the type: "Do not disable exceptions at the customer." will not be helpful to me, but maybe to other people having a similar problem.)

Comment: If you have to disable exceptions when delivering the system, I'd argue that you are not using exceptions correctly.

Comment: Your friend appears to be determined to cause problems for himself. You should *absolutely* try to persuade him of the perils of turning off validation in production. Give him a scenario where the data can be *detected* as completely invalid - would he rather abort the program, or overwrite good data with known bad data? Turning off validation in production is like a racing car driver saying, "I know I can drive safely with a seatbelt at low speeds - so now that I'm racing, I'll take off my seatbelt."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, let me start by saying that you should **never ever ever blindly disable runtime exceptions**.  There is a reason why these terminate your program.  Java has entered a WTF brain-fart bad state and wants to get you out as safely as possible.  Something is clearly wrong with your program and the sooner you know about it the better.  The last thing you want is your customer going along thinking that everything's peachy while their program is crapping all over itself.

I'd argue that the correct way to handle this would be to catch your Exceptions at various levels and provide valid alternatives.  Maybe you can abandon a job and resubmit.  Maybe you provide the user with an error that will notify them of the issue (and might help them avoid it next time).  The point here is you probably shouldn't have completely uncaught (runtime) Exceptions happening in the first place; somewhere in your code, and hopefully at multiple logical levels, you should handle these exceptions as gracefully as programmatically possible.